# finding $x^{f(x)}$ given a point on $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

If we have a function $f(x)$ where any point on the curve can be written as:

$$\left((a), (a(1-f'(a)\ln{a})\right), a>0$$

What is $x^{f(x)}$?

This was a question given to me by my teacher a while back, and i'm still struggling to solve it. He says that the question can be done without the use of any differential equations.

Even though he said not to, I got it into a differential equation of the form:

$$f'(x)= \frac{x-f(x)}{x\ln{x}}$$

Which did not help me at all, since I couldn't form two integrals with respect to $x$ and $y$

I've spent a very long time attempting various ways of approaching the question, however they all led to dead ends.

I am so stuck and would love help with a solution to this (preferably without the use of differential equations, however I would also like to see how you would use differential equations to solve this).

Comment: Does "the curve" mean the graph of $f$?

Comment: @MPW Yes it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take the derivative of $x^{f(x)}$ with respect to $x$ we get:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{f(x)}\right)=\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}+f'(x)\ln{x}\right)x^{f(x)}$$

but from your differential equation:

$$\frac{f(x)}{x}+f'(x)\ln{x}=1$$

Then we have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{f(x)}\right)=x^{f(x)}$$

And so:
$$x^{f(x)}=e^{x+c}$$

Given the point $(1,1)$ is on our curve, we can solve for the value of $c$ to be $-1$.

So our final answer becomes:
$$x^{f(x)}=e^{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y = x(1-y'\ln x)$$
$$y\cdot\frac1x = 1 - y'\ln x$$
$$y\cdot\frac1x + y'\ln x= 1$$
$$(y\ln x)' = 1$$
$$y\ln x = x + C$$
Since $(1,1)$ is on the curve (verify this!), we have $C = -1$:
$$y\ln x = x - 1$$
$$\ln\left(x^y\right) = x - 1$$
$$x^y = \boxed{e^{x-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x) \ln x$. Then, assuming that $f$ is differentiable, we have
$$g'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}+f'(x)\ln x=(1-f'(x)\ln x)+f'(x)\ln x=1$$
which means that $g(x)$ is of the form $g(x)=x+c$ for some constant $c$, and equivalently $f(x)=\frac{x+c}{\ln x}$. Then, we have
$$x^{f(x)}=x^{\frac{x+c}{\ln x}}=(x^\frac{1}{\ln x})^{x+c}=e^{x+c}$$
where the last equality follows from the fact that $x^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}=x^{\log_x e}=e^{\log_x x}=e$. Therefore, we have that $x^{f(x)}=e^{x+c}$ for some constant $c$, or equivalently $x^{f(x)}=de^x$ for some positive constant $d$.

(Finding such form of $g(x)$ comes from observing the differential equation, and trying to rearrange it into some familiar $(uv)'$ if that is possible.)

Edit: It seems that I have not fully used the given condition. As @MPW wrote in the solution, the curve passes the point $(1, 1)$, and we could indeed pinpoint the constant $c$.